# Configure Hosting for Vue JS 2 App on Firebase

Tags: firebase, vuejs2, firebase-hosting

I've deployed my single page vue js web application on Google Firebase. When the source files are requested, firebase returns index.html instead of the .js files the app needs to run. I tried reconfiguring the rewrite for the web application

Old, matches all requests to index.html:

```
"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
```

New, intended to match all requests **except** file requests to index.html:

```
"rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "!**/*.@(js|css|jpg|jpeg|png)",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
```

Now, whenever I go to the link for a js file, i get a 404 error.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after many hours of struggling, I discovered the solution was to upgrade Firebase CLI from 4.1.0 to 4.1.1